# How to import ddl into oracle 12c - ORA-02153

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I created a ddl dump from an Oracle 12c database with SQLDeveloper. The problem is that i can't import it.

At the start it tries to "CONNCT TO" a user (i created the user manually an gave it "catalog" as password). On running the script

```
  CREATE DATABASE LINK "DBINTERNET2T"
   CONNECT TO "CATALOG" IDENTIFIED BY VALUES ':1'
   USING 'DBINTERNET2T';
```

I get

```
ORA-02153: Ungültige VALUES-Kennwortzeichenfolge
02153. 00000 -  "invalid VALUES password string"
*Cause:    An encoded password string does not follow the VALUES clause.
*Action:   Place a proper encoded password string after the VALUES clause.
```

Of course `:1` is not the correct password, but what does this mean?
I also run

```
select password,spare4 from sys.user$ where name='CATALOG';
```

To get hashes and i tried both "password" and "spare4" as values the error is always the same. So How to import such an sql script or how to correctly connect to user "CATALOG"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to "fix" database link creation:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK DBINTERNET2T
   CONNECT TO CATALOG IDENTIFIED BY catalog  --> note that VALUES is missing!
   USING 'DBINTERNET2T';
```

Any improvement?